# Nativescript RadSideDrawer - any way to make it draggable?

Tags: nativescript

I'm new to nativescript and from what I understand certain concepts that I know from pure HTML/JS development don't apply with nativescript XML?

In particular, what method could be used to make the RadListSideDrawer drag-expandable. That is, my app will run on iPad only, and I would like the user to be able to drag-expand the sidedrawer to whichever width they like.

With HTML/CSS this would normally be done via mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove events, adjusting the width dynamically. Can this method be used in nativescript? Also, I'm used to styling a drag-handle using down divs and span or whatnot, but I'm not sure what the analog would be in nativescript.

Comment: what do you mean by drag expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the RadSideDrawer is NOT open source; there is no way that I can think of where you can control the width of the control via dragging.

However, doing a search for "SideDrawer" (as of 2018-06-01) shows three plugins that implement a side drawer on [https://plugins.nativescript.rocks](https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/).

The first plugin [NativeScript-SideDrawer](https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/plugin/nativescript-sidedrawer) is open source; so you could modify the plugin source to support your desire to make the side drawer keep opening until they let go of the mouse.

The second plugin [NativeScript-Foss-SideDrawer](https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/plugin/nativescript-foss-sidedrawer) is a fork of the above; it states it continues where the original author stopped.  So this might be a better choice to start with.

And the third plugins is [nativescript-ui-sidedrawer](https://plugins.nativescript.rocks/plugin/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer) which is the RadSideDrawer you mentioned above (which is not open source, but it might eventually be).